# One to Many Relation in MongoDB with unique value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I wanna have a one to many Relation with unique values.

Error: "MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection"

I have two Schemas.
So what i wanna do, is having a User with an unique email value. The User can create as many Servers as he wants. The Server Schema has a value "admin". So the admin value is the User who created the Server.

One Schema for the User. And another one for Server.

User:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Provide username'],
    trim: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 30,
    match: [
      /^(?=.{3,30}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/,
      'Provide valid username',
    ],
  },
  hash: {
    type: String,
    default: '#number',
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Provide email'],
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 2,
    unique: true,
    match: [
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
      'Provide valid email',
    ],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Provide password '],
    trim: true,
    minlength: 8,
    select: false,
  },
  friends: {
    type: [mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId],
    ref: "User",
    default: [],
  },
  servers: {
    type: [mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId],
    ref: "Server",
    default: [],
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
    immutable: true,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpire: Date,
  verified: Boolean,
  verifiedToken: String,
});
```

Server:

```
const ServerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'provide servername'],
    trim: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 30,
  },
  admin: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: User,
    required: [true, 'provide server admin'],
  },
  rooms: {
    type: [RoomSchema],
    default: [],
  },
  users: {
    type: [mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId],
    default: [],
  },
  invations: {
    type: [InvationSchema],
    default: [],
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
    immutable: true,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});
```

I know why im getting the error. Because the email is unique. So i can only have the value once in a document. So how can i still have a unique email but can have many relations with the User?

Comment: Put _id of the user, who created the server in 'admin' field. When you want to look up all servers created by a user, just query 'server' collection with aggregation to user table.

Comment: so my ServerSchema admin shouldnt have the type of mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId? just a String with the user._id?

Comment: yeah, and its not a string, its an object id

Comment: yeah im already doing it or not? so my admin has the type of mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId. Or is there a different type for this?

Comment: yeah its correct.